# How to add Child Item in an expandable listview? Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Im trying to make an expandable listview where my header is from my database and my child items are static where it is repeatedly shown in every header that was click.

In my case, I already done the header part but whenever I clicked the item in the listview to show the child items the application crashes.

I always have this error.

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
```

Here is my ExpandableListAdapter

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context; 

List<String> child;
private ArrayList<Details> mDetails;
private HashMap<ArrayList<Details>, List<String>> mchildOfDetails;

public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, HashMap<ArrayList<Details>, List<String>> listChildData, ArrayList<Details> details) {
    this._context = context;
    this.mDetails = details;
    this.mchildOfDetails = listChildData;

}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this.mchildOfDetails.get(mDetails.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);

}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, parent,false);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.child_info);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.mchildOfDetails.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.mDetails.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mDetails.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_group_item, null);
    }

    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);


    Details mDetailsobj = mDetails.get(groupPosition);

    lblListDesc.setText(mDetailsobj.getDesc());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

}
```

and here is my fragment where i use the expandable listview

```
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;

List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<ArrayList<Details>, List<String>> listDataChild;

ArrayList<Details> Details;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

....

expListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        prepareChildData();

        listDataChild = new HashMap<ArrayList<Details>, List<String>>();
        listDataChild.put(Details, child);

        listAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataChild, Details);
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

....
}

private void  prepareChildData(){
   child = new ArrayList<String>();

    child.add("One");
    child.add("Two");
    child.add("Three");
}
```

another note:

I think I'm having the error in my getChild().  Because i can't display the child list where the displaying is happening inside the getChildView().

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So, what i have done was to create a new List that will handle the child items

```
//header titles
private ArrayList<DetailsWithNoLocation> mDetailsWithNoLocation;
//child titles
List<String> mlistOtherDetails;
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<ArrayList<Details>, List<String>> mchildOfDetails;


 public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Details> details, List<String> listOtherDetails, HashMap<ArrayList<Details>, List<String>> HashChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this.mDetails = detailsWithNoLocation; //header
    this.mlistOtherDetails = listOtherDetails; // child
    this.mchildOfDetails = HashChildData; //hash data
}
```

then in my getChild() instead of returning what i've used last time i call the new created List

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
   return this.mlistOtherDetails.get(groupPosition);
}
```

i can now display my child views but instead of displaying the three values which are {One, Two, Three} in each row they are displayed separately. In each row one value is displayed so i'm still working on it.